# Error with pip install [url]

Tags: pip, trac, rhel7

I'm attempting to install a plugin for Trac and would like to not use `easy_install` since there is no uninstall for packages installed that way.

So I issued:

```
# pip install https://trac-hacks.org/svn/accountmanagerplugin/tags/acct_mgr-0.4.4
```

And this happened:

```
Collecting https://trac-hacks.org/svn/accountmanagerplugin/tags/acct_mgr-0.4.4
  Using cached https://trac-hacks.org/svn/accountmanagerplugin/tags/acct_mgr-0.4.4
  Cannot unpack file /tmp/pip-fOSusX-unpack/acct_mgr-0.4.4 (downloaded from /tmp/pip-B6tUyR-build, content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8); cannot detect archive format
Cannot determine archive format of /tmp/pip-B6tUyR-build
```

When I browse https://trac-hacks.org/svn/accountmanagerplugin/tags/acct_mgr-0.4.4/, I'm seeing some unpacked files on a server and not an archive.

Is there a way I can download all of those, archive them to a tar.gz or something, and would pip then be able to install?

Or is there a flag with pip that will let it work with non-archived packages?

Comment: Try `pip install svn+https://trac-hacks.org/svn/accountmanagerplugin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to specify the scheme `svn+https`:

```
# pip install svn+https://trac-hacks.org/svn/accountmanagerplugin/tags/acct_mgr-0.4.4
```